# Re-Writing "Fuzzy Join" Functions from R to SQL

Tags: sql, r, join

In the R programming language, I am interested in performing a "fuzzy join" and passing this through a SQL Connection:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

library(RODBC)
library(sqldf)

con = odbcConnect("some name", uid = "some id", pwd = "abc")

sample_query = sqlQuery( stringdist_inner_join(table_1, table_2, by = "id2", max_dist = 2) %>%
  filter(date_1 >= date_2, date_1 <= date_3) )

view(sample_query)
```

However, I do not think this is possible, because the function which us being used for the "fuzzy join" (stringdist_inner_join) is not supported .

I tried to find the source code for this "fuzzy join" function, and found it over here: https://rdrr.io/cran/fuzzyjoin/src/R/stringdist_join.R

**My Question:** Does anyone know if it is possible to (manually) convert this "fuzzy join" function into an SQL format that will be recognized? Are there any quick ways to re-write this function (stringdist_inner_join) such that it can be recognized by Netezza? Are there any pre-existing ways to do this?

Right now I can only execute "sample_query" on locally -  re-writing this function (stringdist_inner_join) would let perform the "sample_query" much faster.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

**Note:**

My data looks like this:

```
table_1 = data.frame(id1 = c("123 A", "123BB", "12 5", "12--5"), id2 = c("11", "12", "14", "13"),
date_1 = c("2010-01-31","2010-01-31", "2015-01-31", "2018-01-31" ))

table_1$id1 = as.factor(table_1$id1)
table_1$id2 = as.factor(table_1$id2)
table_1$date_1 = as.factor(table_1$date_1)

table_2 = data.frame(id1 = c("0123", "1233", "125  .", "125_"), id2 = c("111", "112", "14", "113"),
date_2 = c("2009-01-31","2010-01-31", "2010-01-31", "2010-01-31" ),
date_3 = c("2011-01-31","2010-01-31", "2020-01-31", "2020-01-31" ))


table_2$id1 = as.factor(table_2$id1)
table_2$id2 = as.factor(table_2$id2)
table_2$date_2 = as.factor(table_2$date_2)
table_2$date_3 = as.factor(table_2$date_3)
```

Comment: Maybe this is useful, Using Levenstein Distance: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251168/sql-fuzzy-join-mssql>

Comment: @ TarJae: Thank you so much for your reply! I wonder if it is possible to convert the "Levenstein Distance" into SQL code that is recognizable by R? Is there a straightforward way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: ,@stats555 I think this might be useful: <https://rpubs.com/chrimaho/AddressingTheJohnSmithProblem>

Comment: @ Tarjae: thank you for your reply! I already saw this! I am just wondering: how can the functions from this rpubs link be re-written in such a way so that they can be run on a netezza server?

Comment: Depending on what your fields contain and what you want you may be able to use one of these: https://dwgeek.com/netezza-phonetic-matching-functions-examples.html/

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck: thank you for your reply! I tried looking at the "score_mp" function which might be useful for my problem? However, I am not sure how to incorporate this function into my code - could you please suggest how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Based on your other post about this issue, a solution to the question of how to structure the SQL query was solved:

[SAS: Fuzzy Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70222931/sas-fuzzy-joins)

```
select a.*, b.* 
from table_a a
inner join table_b b
  on (a.date_1 between b.date_2 and b.date_3)
      and (le_dst(a.id1, b.id1) = 1 or a.id2 = b.id2)
```

To get this to run in an R script, I would recommend using [dbplyr](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/) and creating this using `tbl` so you can continue doing basic manipulation of it as if it were a data.frame and dbplyr will translate it into SQL (at least basic commands), then combine everything into a query and eventually pull the data from the query with the `collect()` function.

Edit: Just a note, the `tbl` command will start building a SQL statement and get column names, but it won't run it to pull data until you enter `collect()` at which point, R will send the query to the server, the server will run the query and send the data.

Just keep this in mind because if dbplyr can't translate something to SQL, it will assume it's a SQL command and try to send it, so you won't know there's an error until you try to collect. For example, a function from the `stringr` package, `str_dectect`, isn't implemented in `dbplyr` and so `dbplyr` would send that command to the database, which would throw an error because it doesn't know what that is, but only after running `collect()`. Check out the dbplyr page linked above for details.

```
library(dbplyr)

new_con<- dbConnect(
  odbc(),
  Driver= "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server (as an example)",
  Server = "Server name here",
  uid = "some_id",
  pwd = "abc"
)


sample_query<- dbplyr::tbl(
  new_con,
  dbplyr::sql(
  "select a.*, b.* 
    from table_a a
    inner join table_b b
      on (a.date_1 between b.date_2 and b.date_3)"

sample_data<-sample_query %>%
 filter(silly_example==TRUE) %>%
 collect()
```

Comment: @ Roger 123 : thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to do  the fuzzy join over the server?

Comment: Yes. When you run `tbl`, dbplyr starts building up a SQL query statement but doesn't actually run it. Once you enter `collect()`, then it actually sends the query to the database to get the data and the server will run the query at that time, __not__ R. Before that, it will just look at column names but not actually pull any data. Run `show_query()` to see what the SQL query looks like that it builds.

Comment: @ Roger-123: Thank you so much for your reply! Another question : What is "silly_example" in this answer?

Comment: @ Roger- 123: Regarding the "fuzzy join": as you mentioned, the "stringdist" function  is not implemented in dplyr/dbplyr. This means that in reality, there is no way to run the fuzzy join over the server? Thanks!

Comment: @stats555 silly_example was just non-sense showing that you could put a filter adding on to a sql query.

Comment: @stats555 you can't use 'stringdist' but if you can create an equivalent sql query, you can use the method described above to run the SQL query via R. By using the `tbl` function, you can manually enter a query, then use dbplyr to continue manipulating it before actually running it ON THE SERVER. Check out the dbplyr package documentation for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Roger-123's approach. But here is a variation that might assist:

Assuming you are using remote connections to access the Netezza database, you could do this using dbplyr as follows:

```r
remote_1 = tbl(con, "table_1_name")
remote_2 = tbl(con, "table_2_name")

# create dummy column
remote_1 = mutate(remote_1, ones = 1)
remote_2 = mutate(remote_2, ones = 1)

output = remote_1 %>%
  # cross_join
  inner_join(remote_2, by = "ones", prefix = c("_1","_2")) %>%
  # calculate Levenshtein distance
  mutate(distance = le_dst(id1, id2)) %>%
  # filter to close matches
  filter(distance <= 2)
```

Notes:

- dbplyr does not allow for complex conditions in its joins. Hence we do the most general join possible and then filter.
- If you also want joins by date, then you can put them into the `inner_join` if the conditions are simple, or create another filter condition if they are complex.
- `le_dst` is not an R function and there is no dbplyr translation for it, so dbplyr will pass it to the server as-is.
- Netezza accepts two distance functions for text: `le_dst` and `dle_dst`. You can use whichever you please here.
- `Output` is a query, it will act like a table but it is being generated/calculated on the fly. It has not been written to disk or loaded into R memory. Depending on your application you will want to store/save this.