# R: "Compressing" Plotly Plots

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I made the following scatterplot using plotly (with many points):

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(htmlwidgets)

a = rnorm(100000,10,10)
b = rnorm(100000, 10, 10)
c = as.factor("red")

data_1 = data.frame(a,b,c)

a = rnorm(100000,5,5)
b = rnorm(100000, 5, 5)
c = as.factor("blue")

data_2 = data.frame(a,b,c)

final = rbind(data_1, data_2)

my_plot = ggplot(final, aes(x=a, y=b, col = c)) + geom_point()

ggplotly = ggplotly(my_plot)

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(ggplotly, "ggplotly.html")
```

[image]

**Problem:** The computer I am using is taking a long time to run the above code (e.g. the picture I posted is only based on 1000 points), and usually results in a "pandoc error". Is it possible to somehow "compress" the interactive html file that is produced (perhaps in lower resolution) such that it can run on my (slower) computer?

Comment: 200k points is quite heavy or a SVG/D3 based plot. You could try using `plot_ly()` and set the trace `type = "scattergl"` to use WebGL/regl instead (this has other drawbacks). Another option is using `partial_bundle` but I don't think it'll make a big difference.

Comment: @ ismiresregal: thank you for your reply! I will try this! Can you please take a look at this question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231544/re-writing-fuzzy-join-functions-from-r-to-sql thank you for everything!

Comment: As an addition: [Here](https://plotly.com/python/v3/compare-webgl-svg/#svg) you can find a UserWarning summarizing the issue: `Due to browser limitations, the Plotly SVG drawing functions have a hard time graphing more than 500k data points for line charts, or 40k points for other types of charts.` (from plotly.py which under the hood - just as the R API - uses plotly.js)